# IP of my application running on azure is black listed due to some trozan attack. Email delivery failed after that.What can I do to stop this?

Tags: azure

IP of my application running on  azure is black listed due to some trozan attack. Email delivery failed after that.What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must close the security hole in your application and do a restore (or better a new setup) from a known-good source. Without this, everything else serves no purpose, as it will happen again immediately.

Then you must contact the blacklist providers and prove to them, that you took action and are now trustworthy again. **You must understand, that from the point-of-view of the Internet community your server is now a bad actor or even a criminal actor**.

It might be best to simply create a new instance (with a new IP address), do a clean setup of the **fixed** application there and maybe use a different DNS name, then just drop the infected instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help..Eugen..Sure I will do that...Is it efficient to host another web api that will deliver email, if something goes wrong with mail delivery in my main app?